# CSS column count overflow issue in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using the following code to split an unordered list into two columns, which works fine, except for chrome. Here's my code:

```
.column-list{margin:15px 0 0 0;padding:0;list-style:none;-moz-column-count:2;-webkit-column-count:2;column-count:2}
.column-list li{margin:0 0 15px 0;background:#fff;border-radius:5px;font-size:120%;line-height:normal;font-weight:700;display:block}
.column-list a{padding:25px;display:block}
```

And here's what's happening (it's splitting the li in half and putting it in the next column):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `break-inside:avoid` to your children elements. Fully prefixed, it looks like this:

```css
.column-list li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
                 break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Another note on this: technically, the browser only renders a single column and then cuts it at exact points and displays the segments side by side. What this means in practice is that if you have a `box-shadow` on an element and the cut happens immediately before or after it, you'll see the rendering of that shadow on another column, which obviously looks weird.
Setting appropriate top and bottom `margin`s on the element, according to the size of the `box-shadow` fixes this issue.